# Куда положить файлы, чтобы их можно было читать и видоизменять?

Tags: android, kotlin

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы у меня непосредственно в приложении андроид лежали файлы по типу `.json`.

Куда их положить — я знаю всего два места, это папка `raw` и `assets`, прочитать содержимое у меня получилось отлично, а вот заменить значения у меня не получается.

Узнал только, что в папке raw хранятся ресурсы и их не получится изменять и дополнять непосредственно во время работы приложения, а про паку assets такой информации не нашел.

Может я конечно не так открываю:

```
var JSON_STRING_OF_COMPL = assets.open("complite")
```

При попытке найти функцию write какую-нибудь, мне предлагается только `.bufferedReader()`, либо не так открываю под запись, либо нужно в другое место класть, только вот куда — не знаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сохраняйте файлы во внутреннее хранилище [`filesDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getFilesDir()) либо в [`cacheDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getCacheDir()). Файлы, созданные таким способом, можно использовать только внутри вашего приложения.

Например, запись строки в файл:

```kotlin
File(filesDir, "example.txt").writeText("Hello World")
```

Чтение из файла:

```kotlin
val content = File(filesDir, "example.txt").readText()
```

Если файл достаточно большой, то используйте BufferedReader и BufferredWriter. Работа с файлами точно такая же, как в Java.

Посмотрите в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage), какие способы хранения данных есть в Андроид.

Comment: Я находил подобное решение, но разве при каждом запуске активити файлы не будут перезаписываться?
Допустим у меня хранится
`{
  "list": {
    "item_1":0,
    "item_2":0,
    "item_3": 0,
    "item_4": 0
  }
}`
И каждый раз, если я буду менять значения, то после завершении цикла жизни приложения и при запуске, все внесенные изменения будут сбрасываться до начальных состояний. А мне как раз таки нужно сделать так, чтобы эти файлы были с приложением и менялись, пока пользователь пользуется, и только при переустановке сбрасывались до значений по умолчанию

Comment: Файлы в директории `filesDir` будут храниться до удаления приложения. А файлы из `cacheDir` могут быть почищены системой.

Comment: Хорошо, если я правильно Вас понял, то как мне в таком случае, сделать, чтобы добавление было одноразовым, только при первом запуске активити, а не при каждом?

Comment: Вы можете, например, сделать проверку на существование файла. Если файл еще не создан, значит это первый запуск приложения, создайте новый файл и запишите исходные данные.

Comment: Тоочно! Спасибо большое)