# Как сделать запись в json файл?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

Как реализовать запись в файл? У меня в assets есть json файл и чтение с него происходит хорошо, а вот запись как делать нигде не могу найти.

Вот код:

```
 binding.apply {
            buton.setOnClickListener { 
                write_sjon()

                read_json()

                for (i in 0..arr.size - 1) {
                    if ((edittext1.text.toString() == arr[i]) and (edittext2.text.toString() == arr[i + 1])) {
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        break
                    }
                    if (i == 6) break

                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun read_json() {
        var json: String? = null

        try {
            val inputStream: InputStream = assets.open("login.json")
            json = inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }

            val jsonar = JSONArray(json)

            for (i in 0..jsonar.length() - 1) {
                val jsonobj = jsonar.getJSONObject(i)
                arr.add(jsonobj.getString("login"))
                arr.add(jsonobj.getString("password"))
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("Exception", "Json file not find")
        }
    }
```

В конце еще есть метод

```
fun write_sjon() {}
```

В него-то мне и надо добавить возможность записи в файл,желателен простой пример для понимания на примере логин:пароль

```
JSoN файл:

[
  {
    "login": "Pimp",
    "password": "123"
  },
  {
    "login": "Lops",
    "password": "443"
  },
  {
    "login": "Hos",
    "password": "295"
  },
  {
    "login": "Kok",
    "password": "728"
  }
]
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Куда положить файлы, чтобы их можно было читать и видоизменять?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1442833/%d0%9a%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: Записать в assets нельзя, [сохраняйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1442839) новые файлы в filesDir или в cacheDir.